# PHP Echo SUM session value & form select

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP echo statement of a session value like this:

`<?php echo $userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount'] ;?>`

I have a form select element like this:

```
<select id="Lock" name="Lock">
                      <option value="1" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
                      <option value="2">2 Years</option>
                      <option value="3">3 Years</option>
                      <option value="4">4 Years</option>
                    </select>
```

I'm trying to update the `<?php echo $userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount'] ;?>` output by taking what the user selects in the select value id Lock with this session value while interacting with the form?

I've tried `<?php echo ($userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount'] * #Lock) ;?>` with no luck.

What is the easiest way to update this value as the user interacts with the select form input in real time?

Comment: @pr1nc3 okay thanks...any pointers where to do this?

Comment: Give me some time to provide you an answer that explains what you need. I will come back to you.

Comment: @pr1nc3 thanks so much!  I could not find an answer that was very clear...I think this would be a good question/answer combo for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
renewAmount = <?= $userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount']; ?>
function calc(year){
    var amount = renewAmount*year;
    // here you can perform an ajax request to update the amount on server
}
</script>
<select id="Lock" name="Lock" onchange="calc(this.value)">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
  <option value="2">2 Years</option>
  <option value="3">3 Years</option>
  <option value="4">4 Years</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because your PHP is interpretted before your HTML. That's the whole point of PHP. One way you can work around that is to store your `$userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount']` into a Javascript variable and works with this variable. EX:

```
<script>var RenewAgreementAmount = <?php echo $userinfo['RenewAgreementAmount'] ?></script>
```

And then, you can put the value of the newly created `RenewAgreementAmount` javascript variable where you want to show it using :

```
<span id="renewAgreementAmountField"></span>
<script>
    document.getElementById("renewAgreementAmountField").innerHTML = RenewAgreementAmount
</script>
```

You can then work with your variable and change the value.

```
RenewAgreementAmount = RenewAgreementAmount * document.getElementById("Lock").value;
```

If you want to update the value on the server side, you can use an AJAX request ( XMLHttpRequest in plain Javascript) with your new variable.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so you have this dropdown and you want to get the real-time options everytime something is selected:

```
   $('#Lock').on('change',function() {
       var option
       option = $('#Lock').val()

       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: "your_php_file.php",
           dataType: 'data',
           data: {
               option: option
           }
       })
   })
```

This code will get the value every time a value is selected from this dropdown and will make an ajax call to your php class that you want to handle. your php class name should be put in the `url:` field

After that in your php you just retrieve the data like this:

```
$option=$_POST['option'];
```

Well this means that you execute an ajax call everytime something is selected. I propose that you put a button and trigger the `ajax` when the user clicks the button, so setup and `onClick` event.

Don't forget in your html-head to include the jquery version :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: anychance you can do a fiddle?  I'm having trouble making this work.

Answer (score 1):

Approach using some jQuery, would be something like this--

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["RenewAgreementAmount"] = 50;

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="Lock" name="Lock">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
            <option value="2">2 Years</option>
            <option value="3">3 Years</option>
            <option value="4">4 Years</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Lock").bind("change", function(index){
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    //console.log("Changed to: " + value);
                    $.post("updateSessionValue.php". {"newVal": value});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### For updateSessionValue.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["RenewAgreementAmount"] = $_POST["newVal"];
```

Obviously, just an example code... make sure to take all the necessary security precautions!